# Searching HWPF packages in Apache POI v3.11

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've just downloaded the bins from Apache POI (http://poi.apache.org/download.html). Now I want to work with Word-files (doc - HWPF, docx - XWPF), but can't find the package

```
org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
```

But these classes are used in the examples on the project page (e.g. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hwpf/Word2Forrest.java).

Can you help me?!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use maven and your troubles will evaporate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed on the [Apache POI Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), for HWPF you need both the main poi jar (eg `poi-3.11-20141221.jar`) *and* the scratchpad poi jar (eg `poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar`)

With the POI Scratchpad jar on your classpath, you'll have HWPF available to you